# Create https session between server and client

Tags: tls, openssl, server, client

I'm doing a project about security transactions and i'm wondering if to establish a connection based on https both client and server need to have a ssl implementation installed to preform the handshake protocol.
Anyone could help me out here?
Cumps.

Comment: There is a bunch of great information on this subject in a similar question. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37701/is-encryption-in-https-done-by-the-browser-or-by-the-system

Comment: Thank you @DavidHoude. Next time I'll search better before ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the client and server both need to support SSL/TLS.

All modern web browsers ship with this support baked in, such as [NSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/An_overview_of_NSS_Internals) in Firefox. Unless you have a one off use case, I don't see you needing to worry much about the clients support for SSL/TLS.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. The browsers will make the handshake protocol with the server?

Comment: Yes. All modern browsers implement TLS and will have no problem negotiating with a standard HTTPS server configuration.